# Connecting to SOAP server from Node.js producing ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, http

I am trying to connect to SOAP server from Node.js using a HTTP request. It is however producing a `ECONNRESET` error more or less straight away. I believe this is to do with timeout but cannot seem to fix it. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. The port, host and path are all correct.

My HTTP request is:

```
  var postRequest = {
      host : "t1.webservice.secure.ddts.defra.gov.uk",
      path: "/defraDataTransferPublicNWSE.asmx",
      SOAPAction: "http://www.defra.gov.uk/TransferData",
      port: 443,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body2)
      }
  };

  var buffer = "";

  var req = http.request( postRequest, function( res )    {
     console.log( res.statusCode );
     var buffer = "";
     res.on( "data", function( data ) { buffer = buffer + data; } );
     res.on( "end", function( data ) { console.log( buffer ); } );
  });
  req.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log( "----ERROR----" ); console.log(err);
  });
  req.write( body2 );
  req.end();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must use `https` module vs `http` module.

The next problem with the certificate of authorization center.

Simple, you can set `rejectUnauthorized` option to `false`, but this is not very good.

The best option:

- Download Symantec Intermediate CA (ICA) Certificate (`Symantec Class 3
  Secure Server CA - G4`) from this [page](https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=SO26896)
- install module `ssl-root-cas`
- add certificate before request:

*

```
var sslRootCAs = require('ssl-root-cas/latest')
    .inject()`
    .addFile( __dirname + '/Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4.cer' );
```